# Showing message without any buttons in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, message

I would like to create an info message box in Windows Phone.

It should look like a single text message, that's shown on screen for X seconds, and I doesn't have any confirmation buttons
as **MessageBox.Show()** does. It would be used to show user some messages about the app progress, like "*file download started*",
or "*preferences saved*".

I've tried to create something like that, using Popup element, but it seems a bit different of what I want to
make.

With the popup I can create something like that

```
canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(popupCloseEvent);
```

For example, which closes this popup when user taps it.

or something similar. (Maybe can implement a timer there to close it after a few secs)

Are there better ways to create such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the either the Message Dialog or Overlay controls in the Coding4Fun toolkit.

Found here: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/

They are really simple and easy to use controls.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly, what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In Xaml:

```
    <Popup Tap="Popup_Tap"></Popup>
```

In code behind:

```
    private void Popup_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Popup).IsOpen = false;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I described the problem a bit messy. I've already made a possibility for popup to close, when it's tapped, but that's not the thing, I want. I need a popup/message, that would close without any user's action. Just shown for some time.

Comment: Then i guess you should look into [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) with which you can create a timer.